# RSPEC how to post to a controller? What's wrong with this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I'm trying to post to my controller in RSPEC, see anything wrong with this? It's failing w/o error:

```
it "should store create an IncomingMail record" do
  lambda {      
    post 'create', {
           "from" => 'XXX',
           "to" => 'XXX',
           "cc" => 'XXX', 
           "subject" => 'XXX', 
           "message_text" => 'XXX',
           "message_html" => 'XXX' }
  }.should change { IncomingMail.count }.by(1)
end
```

**Updated:**

```
it "should store create an IncomingMail record" do
  post :create,
       :from => 'xx',
       :to => 'xx',
       :cc => 'xx',
       :subject => 'xx',
       :message_text => 'xx',
       :message_html => 'xx'

  mail = IncomingMail.last(:order => 'created_at desc')
  mail.from.should == 'xx'
end
```

**Controller**

```
class IncomingMailsController < ApplicationController

  require 'iconv'

  #make sure that rails doesn't raise an exception because we have no way of knowing the token
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def create

    begin
      @incoming_mail = IncomingMail.create(
                                            :from => params[:from],
                                            :to => params[:to],
                                            :cc => params[:cc], 
                                            :subject => params[:subject], 
                                            :message_text => message_text_utf8,
                                            :message_html => message_html_utf8
                                            )
.....
```

Comment: Added an updated approach. Still it is failing. In the test.log file I see the record being created, but then it shows: SQL (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "incoming_mails"
  SQL (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK

Comment: errors with      Failure/Error: mail.from == 'xx'
     NoMethodError:
       You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
       You might have expected an instance of Array.
       The error occurred while evaluating nil.from

Comment: Also tried wrapping it in a lambda, lambda {....}.should change(IncomingMail, :count).by(1)   same issue, didn't update the count. Does this have something to do with the fact that The controller create's the record and that the record isn't being created inside of rspec?

Comment: I checked the logs. While the test above is hitting the controller, it is never going inside the method def create. Y?

Comment: I do have this in my rake routes: POST   /incoming_mails(.:format)                                                                         {:controller=>"incoming_mails", :action=>"create"}

Comment: It might be best if you include your relevant controller and model code as well.

Comment: @Pan updating now. Any ideas?

Comment: @Pan is RSPEC the right tool for this or should I be using cucumber/webrat? Just learning how to write tests in rails now.

Comment: RSPEC is a fine tool for this. I suspect your code is not giving an error because your model is not being created so the response that is being rendered is just an error page. Try doing this on the model level with the same params first and check it if works: mail = IncomingMail.create(...); p mail.valid?; p mail.from. Are the results what you expect them to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i do it :

Route Example :

```
post  'train_ability/:ability' => :train_ability, :as => 'train_ability'
```

Spec :

```
it "should increase the strength ability by one point and also update the strength_points by one if strength is the trained ability" do
    @user.str = 10
    @user.str_points = 0
    @user.save!
    post :train_ability, :ability => 'str'
    @user.reload
    flash[:error].should be_nil
    @user.str_points.should == 1
    @user.str.should == 11
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems to be very heavy? Should I not be using rspec for this, is cucumber more appropriate?

Comment: Also, I don't see where any of the params are being posted?

Comment: Thanks again but I just don't see how this applies to the question? What am I missing? thanks

Comment: Rspec is ok for this. Take a look at the post inside the spec and you will see the :ability param. Why do you think it does not apply ? I use that all the time to post in my rspec methods.

Comment: For some reason a simple `post :create` always throws `ThreadError: already initialized` for me :/